# Can the word nervous be used like this?

Tags: word-usage

> My middle school was nervous.

Like the above sentence, can the the word  nervous be used for a thing?

Comment: What was your school nervous about? Was it afraid the children would not like its new colours? You could use it in the right context, although it would be some job to create a context for this! Without any context, the answer is _yes, but you probably are not saying what you think you are saying_. Please provide more detail :)

Comment: Since we are now garnering speculative answers, please [edit your question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/200442/edit) to provide more details of what you mean by that sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

[image]

or are you trying to say that the time you went to the middle school was a time of nervousness?

If so, no you cannot use that construct.

Here is another one :)

[image]

Comment: +1 for the picture, but this isn't really an answer.

Comment: I know. I cannot post images in a comment :) I tried to make it an answer